# same query, dramatic different performances on different data. MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, limit

So, I have this huge database with 40 Millions entries.

the query is a simple (a_view is a view!)

```
select * from a_view where id > x LIMIT 10000
```

this is the behavior I get: If x is a little number (int) the query is super fast.
when x > 29 Millions the query starts to take minutes. if it is closer to 30 Millions it takes hours. and so on...

why is that? what can I do to avoid this?

I am using InnoDB as engine, tables have indexes.

the value of the limit is a critical one, it affects performances. if it is small the query is always fast. but if x is close to 30Millions then I need to be very careful to set it not too big (less than 300 hundreds), and still it is quite slow, but doesn't take forever

If you need more details, feel free to ask.

EDIT: here is the explain

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aH    | index  | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 39      | NULL                | 3028439 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 4       | odb.aH.albumID      |       1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aHT   | ref    | PRIMARY,albumID | albumID | 4       | odb.a.albumID       |       4 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 4       | odb.aHT.id          |       1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 4       | odb.t.genre         |       1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ar    | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 4       | odb.t.artist        |       1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure the id column is indexed?

Comment: What are the tables/views and what are the indexes?

Comment: In theory, if you have an index on "id", there should be little difference in performance.

Comment: yes the id column is indexed on the table it comes from, the view is created joining several tables, all indexed. @Michael what do you mean by little difference? I think mine is huge indeed

Comment: Have you looked at EXPLAIN? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: Another suggestion, see if your database spans different storage media, you can have slow or faulty disk/node.

Comment: I have a ref=NULL on a primary key (indexed) of the biggest table, is it the problem? but I don't understand what does that mean

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you add an `ORDER BY id` (ascending or descending) to the query?

Comment: @Ryan not much it's very slow

Comment: We'll need the definition of a_view to determine where the problem may lie.

Comment: I attached the result of the explain for that query

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess. Basically, your view is a select on some tables. The "id" could be a row number. The larger your "x" is, the more select rows need to be created (and discarded) before you can get whatever data you want. That is why your query slows down when your "x" increases.

If this is true, one solution could be to create a table that contains the rownum and a primary key sorted by whatever "order by" you are using. Once you have that table, you can join it with the rest of your data and select your data window by a rownum range.

Comment: sorry, how do I verify if is that is the problem? and I haven't quite understand how do I create that table.

Comment: I'm looking at different ideas as to what could be the cause of your performance issue. It would help if you post a_view definition. In particular, what does "id" corresponds to?

Comment: id corresponds to odb.t.id which is equal to odb.aHT.id (which is in the explain) . I join the two tables t and aHT on those columns.